# Is there a way to combine two raster mapbox layears

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to implement something similar to [mapbox-compare](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-compare/)  feature. But instead of having side by side sync maps I need to show one layer over another but only inside some area(s) on map e.g.
[image]
Lets say i want to combine default lite map style with some [third-party raster source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/)
Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/e9wqdfgn/11/

```
function getD3() {
  var bbox = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  var center = map.getCenter();
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  // 512 is hardcoded tile size, might need to be 256 or changed to suit your map config
  var scale = (512) * 0.5 / Math.PI * Math.pow(2, zoom);

  var d3projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([center.lng, center.lat])
    .translate([bbox.width/2, bbox.height/2])
    .scale(scale);

  return d3projection;
}
```

but without d3.js

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this:

1. Position two maps directly above each other, same dimensions.
2. Use [mapbox-gl-sync-move](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-sync-move) to keep their positions in sync.
3. Use [CSS clipping](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) so that most of the top one is not shown. The code within [`mapbox-gl-compare`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-compare/blob/main/index.js) might help.

Comment: thanks, but i need to create some kind of "holes" on some areas on map (more then 1). E.g on several US states

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use mapbox

It has very simple integration, sharing video for your reference https://youtu.be/-VQ4wheGruI